# Using fopen twice

Tags: php, fopen

I would like to open 2 url's using open

```
$url = 'http://xtreme-jumps.eu/demos.txt';
$url2 = 'http://cosy-climbing.net/demoz.txt';
```

Something like this... but it's not working

```
$handle = @fopen($url, "r");
$handle .= @fopen($url2, "r");
```

I need to join them because later i'll search there

```
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($buffer, $map) !== FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" and why not just use two handles?

Comment: @j08691 i've added the piece of code related to why i need to join them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$handles=array();

$handles[]=@fopen($url, "r");
$handles[]=@fopen($url2, "r");

foreach($handles as $handle){
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($buffer, $map) !== FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);

}
```

or better:

```
$urls=array(
    'http://xtreme-jumps.eu/demos.txt',
    'http://cosy-climbing.net/demoz.txt'
);


foreach($urls as $url){
    $handle=@fopen($url, "r");
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($buffer, $map) !== FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate handles. You need to use `fread()` (or just `file_get_contents()`) if you want the actual file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, that won't work because `handle` is a resource, not the *contents* of the web page you're trying to open.

If you want to join the *content* together, you need to open the first URL, get the content, open the second and get the content, then join the content.

You can reuse `handle` for the second open if you finish all your operations on the first but you can't have a single handle connected to two URLs at the same time. You *certainly* can't do that by attempting to concatenate them.

If you want to access the two URLs concurrently, just use two different resource handles.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead?  `fopen` returns a resource handle, which you later use to read (or write) to.