# Try fopen twice?

Tags: php, fopen

I have never had PHP's `fopen` function fail on my localhost. However, if `fopen` were to fail on the first try, would it be useful to try it a second time, as shown in the function below?

```
<?php

function tryOp2 ($filename, $how) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, $how);

    if($handle === false) {
        $handle = fopen($filename, $how);
        if($handle === false){
            return false;       
        }
    }

    return $handle;
}

?>
```

Comment: What's the chance that a file fails to open and works a couple milliseconds later? Seems pointless to me unless you change the file between the calls.

Comment: Why do tou think the second try will work?

Comment: I think that would just be unnecessary overhead. It should at least wait a few moments before trying again anyways. If this question is asking if it's a good idea, then I'm voting to close based on opinion.

Comment: @cabellicar123 I hate to assume, but if the OP is fopening an online resource, i.e a webpage, then it is possible that the website was temporarily unavailable for that moment in time, and that second fopen could successfully establish a connection. I agree with Rich (in answers), that the OP should at least delay the second one, for a higher chance.

Comment: @DaveChen Yes my assumption that the code was as stated and that a couple of milliseconds would probably not matter. Actually checking the error and delaying before a second call if necessary could possibly be beneficial. Just not the way the code was originally written.

Comment: `would it be useful to try it a second time`... **no**, You should just handle the error. Ask yourself, Why not do recursion or try a 1000+ times, till it opens? If its could possible cause infinite loop then, it answers your original question... dont do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where this will indeed help.  You may even be able to improve your chances of recovery if you put a short delay before trying again.  If this is a long-running script, especially, it can be very useful.

There are certain file operations which PHP caches (fstat, for example), but in these instances, PHP will only cache successful results and any failed call can be tried again without any worry you'll get a cached failure.

Comment: Thank you Rich. Adding a few seconds of `sleep ()` is a good idea. Does anyone have an opinion on how many seconds of sleep there should be?

Comment: It's a tradeoff.  It depends on the expected reasons for the fopen failure.  If you've got files that are being locked for a few seconds of writing by the application, then make it just a few more seconds.  If you are instead concerned about other applications holding locks (which you can never be sure of their duration), then waiting for a single second might be more appropriate because you don't want to wait indefinitely; you are just trying to avoid failing in the case of a transient lock which was only being held for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend it. Instead try to figure out why it did not work.

Check and see if the file exists with [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: Using file_exists before fopen is pointless.  Fopen will return an error if the file does not exist and the file may have disappeared between the call to file_exists and fopen anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather say use fopen with different permission. If you are giving one more chance to open a file that might be busy with some other process may be that will help you. But it doesn't make too much difference as virtually code will not take too much time to reach into second try. Its better if you want to just read the file use the flag with fopen. Hence you will not have to use try twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$handles=array();

$handles[]=@fopen($url, "r");

$handles[]=@fopen($url2, "r");

foreach($handles as $handle){
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    if(strpos($buffer, $map) !== FALSE)
        $matches[] = $buffer;
}
fclose($handle);

}
```

as @stewe answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865434/using-fopen-twice).